# Adding "Edit" button with jQuery .append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an application that would allow adding tasks to the list,
and I want to add an edit button, that would allow user to edit each item from the list and then save or delete the amended item. Basically I want my .append code to attach an "Edit" button to each row.

Here is my current .append code

```
var id_counter = 0; 

if ( valid ) {function increment(){id_counter++;}   increment();
        var $task = $("<div class='taskList'  id='"+ id_counter +"'><ul class='taskScreen2'><tr>" 
            + "<td><h1>" + type.val() + "</h1></td>"
            + "<td class='title'><h3>" +  title.val() + "</h3></td>"  
            + "<td>" + wordcount.val() + "</td>"  
            + "<td><p>" + description.val() + "</p></td>"  
            + "<td>" + deadline.val() + "</td>"
            +"<td><button onclick='edit("+id_counter+")'>"+"edit"+"</button></td>"
            + "</tr></ul></div>"
        ).appendTo("#tasks2 tbody");
```

Comment: Please post a complete question, not a follow up linking to another question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question properly, but I think this should do what you like.

```
if ( valid ) {
var $task = $("<tr class='taskList'>" 
    + "<td><h1>" + type.val() + "</h1></td>"
    + "<td class='title'><h3>" +  title.val() + "</h3></td>"  
    + "<td>" + wordcount.val() + "</td>"  
    + "<td><p>" + description.val() + "</p></td>"  
    + "<td>" + deadline.val() + "</td>"
//new button
    + "<td><button onclick='edit()'>"+ "Edit" + "</button></td>"
    + "</tr>"
).appendTo("#tasks2 tbody");
```

if you want to act differently depending on the row, you could call the edit function with a parameter. e.g edit(row_id)

**EDIT**

```
var id_counter

var $task = $("<tr class='taskList' id='"+ id_counter +"'>"
```

for the addition of the id in the code and

```
+"<td><button onclick='edit("+id_counter+")'>"+"edit"+"</button></td>"
```

for the button code

you could start with `id_counter = 0;` and then add plus one each time

Comment: Thank you for this. How can I define to edit each row separately, because when new rows are being created they all fall under 'taskList' class.

Comment: this is up to you. As an example you could add an Id to each row, and then call the function with this id as a parameter.

Comment: Can you advise me please, I used `var $task = $("<tr class='taskList' id='"+(id_counter ++)+"'>" `  along with `var id_counter = 0;`before. But id still stays 0 for every new item. @cs041z1

Comment: without the whole code, I can't know for sure. One possible reason is that you instantiate the variable each time the code is runing. That way (if the code is executed onclick) on each click it restarts counting at 0 and even though it was 1 before it starts again.

Comment: Hey, I edited the code in my question. Basically I am calling the function after .append is done. Any ideas of how I could make this work?

Comment: get the counter_id outside the scope of the edit function. The way you do it, each time you add a row, the counter is becoming 0. set it as global. Also the id_counter(); what does it do? shouldn't it be the increment() ?

Comment: `var id_counter = 0;if ( valid ) {function increment(){id_counter++;} increment();` So I put it like that but the ID still stays the same for each item, also when I click edit button console says "edit is not defined"

Comment: have you created a function called edit that will be fired after the click in the button?

Comment: completely forgot about that! At the moment I want to get the id part working so that every new item has a unique id. Do you have any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: If you post a larger part of your code i might be able to help. wihtout the code no idea.

Comment: I edited the code in my question. Thanks for sticking around!

Comment: try adding a console.log inside the increment function to check that it does increment the counter

Comment: Where is your code placed? is it within a function? the function is within the html or in a separate file?

Comment: It is in a separate js file that's loaded into html file.